# Can we refresh Partial Copy sandbox without any data just like developer sandbox

Tags: metadata, sandbox, data, sandbox-refresh, partial-sandbox

I have a partial copy sandbox created recently and I see that Salesforce loaded around 1.5GB of data from Production. While refreshing partial copy sandbox, I have created a sandbox template including all objects.

My requirement is to just create sandbox with all metadata but no data - just like how it creates a developer sandbox. Because, when data is created in partial copy - it's very incomplete, in terms of our functionality. So **I would like to create partial copy sandbox with only metadata and use Ownbackup tool to seed the data what we needed.**

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Comment: If you want a sandbox with no data, I think you'd have to go with a Dev Pro sandbox instead. It's limited to 1GB of data, but this should be sufficient for many use cases where you'd use a Partial Copy Sandbox.

Comment: I think you can create a Sandbox Template with no objects selected, then create your partial sandbox using that template.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCheng it worked for me, I am able to create sandbox with no objects template and then I started data seeding with Ownbackup

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you for replying me on the query, much appreciated. For our company, we already have partial copy available and we don't have Dev Pro sandbox.

Comment: @DavidCheng - My understanding was that if an object is excluded from a template, both the metadata and data are excluded from the refresh.  It sounds like you had a different experience.  Are you saying that excluding an object from the template still brings over the metadata, but no data for that record?

Comment: @MikePaisner Yes, see also this [document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387049&type=1).